# What is [jbd2/dm-3-8] and [kdmflush]? And why are they constantly on iotop?

Tags: linux, monitoring

Using Fedora for a small Samba and development server.

Comment: I gave some details on how I tracked down what `jbd2` was doing when I had it showing up at the top of `iotop` all the time here: https://serverfault.com/a/801223/181704

Answer (score 22, accepted):

They're kernel threads.

[`[jbd2/%s]`](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux-2.6.git;a=blob;f=fs/jbd2/journal.c;hb=HEAD) are used by JBD2 (the journal manager for ext4) to periodically flush journal commits and other changes to disk.

[`[kdmflush]`](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux-2.6.git;a=blob;f=drivers/md/dm.c;hb=HEAD) is used by Device Mapper to process deferred work that it has queued up from other contexts where doing immediately so would be problematic.